# Optional Parameter always filled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a method in a controller:

```
public ActionResult SendNotification(Guid? id=null, SendNotification notification =null)
```

It responds to `/Apps/SendNotification/{guid}?{SendNotification properties}`

SendNotification is a model with multiple string properties.

My issue is that SendNotification is NEVER null. No matter how I call the action .NET seems to always instantiate an object of SendNotification (with all fields null).

I even tested with the `System.Web.Http.FromUri` and `System.Web.Http.FromBody` and it still does that.

Any ideas?

Note: this is not WebApi. This is regular MVC.

My project only have the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Added above. Note: in my original posting there was an error in the Url of my request (I fixed it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is Model Binding tricking you.

Since it doesn't find any Parameter to bind to the Model, all properties are null but the model is still instantiated by default.

Instead of checking for the Model to be null, check for one of your main property (such as ID) to be null.

Comment: ok... that workaround would work, however, it seems like a bug to me. Why would C# have to instantiate the model if there is no data that leads to that.

Comment: I don't see it as bug. The model binder needs to instantiate the model in order to know which parameter to look for. Then, it binds the values to the matched properties, if none are found, then nothing is bound.

Comment: Ok. I have accepted it as the answer (even though I do not really like the logic C# is using). Thanks.